# VueJS not interating through my data correctly?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

Trying to fetch a list of plans from my external API but it doesn't seem to be rendering in my frontend correctly, could someone help me out?

Returned data:

```
{"data":[{"name":"first_plan","slug":"firstplan","stripe_plan":"dkskdkskd","cost":50},{"name":"second_plan","slug":"secondplan","stripe_plan":"dkskdksk","cost":100},{"name":"third_plan","slug":"thirdplan","stripe_plan":"kfksdkk","cost":200}]}]
```

Template:

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="plan in plans" :key="plan.slug">
    {{ plan }}
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
computed: {
    plans() { return this.$store.state.plans; }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.$store.dispatch("accountBilling/fetch");
  },
```

actions.js:

```
export default {
  async fetch({ commit }) {
    return await this.$axios.get(`/accounts/billing/plans`)
      .then(response => { commit('setPlans', response.data); response.data })
      .catch(error => { throw error })
  },
}
```

getters.js:

```
export default {
  getPlans: state => state.plans,
}
```

mutations:

```
export default {
  setPlans: (state, plans) => state.plans = plans,
}
```

state.js:

```
export default () => ({
  plans: {}
})
```

index.js:

```
import state from './state';
import actions from './actions';
import getters from './getters';
import mutations from './mutations';

export default {
  namespaced: true,
  state,
  actions,
  getters,
  mutations
}
```

Comment: what is not rendering correctly? do you see anything or just not the way you want to?

Answer (score 0):

A few observations:

**Problem 1:**

```js
commit('setPlans', response.data);
```

That should probably be `commit('setPlans', response.data.data);` instead, assuming you want to pull out the `data` array from your server response.

**Problem 2:**

```js
.then(response => { commit('setPlans', response.data); response.data })
```

Not sure why there's a `response.data` on the end? I'm guessing you're trying to resolve the promise to `response.data` but you'd need an explicit `return` for that to work.

**Problem 3:**

```js
return await ...
```

It's generally considered an anti-pattern to use `return await`. There are edge cases where it's acceptable but I don't think they apply here. Instead just use `return` and leave out the `await`. You can ditch the `async` modifier too.

e.g. See https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-return-await

**Other potential problems:**

The initial value for your state seems odd. `plans: {}` should surely be `plans: []`?

Your getter isn't actually being used. Don't feel the need to create a getter just for the sake of it. Getters are just like computed properties on components, if you aren't computing anything you don't need them.

Comment: Cheers! It's definitly improved the situation, I've now got three dots and when I hover it says `invokable propety getter`, it's returning something just not in the right way, it isn't display as an array (data) like the others.

Comment: @notatroll The three dots thing is just how a browser displays property getters. Vue rewrites all your data to make it reactive using property getters and setters. You need to click to find out what the current value is. I'm unclear from your comment whether your problem is now solved. In your template you had `{{ plan }}`, which should be outputting a JSON version of each `plan` object.